# Why is sbt-native-packager staging bin/start as a directory instead of a script?

Tags: scala, sbt, docker, sbt-native-packager

I'm using sbt-native-packager and sbt-docker to generate Docker images as described in [this tutorial](http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2014/06/akka-clustering-with-sbt-docker-and-sbt-native-packager/). The Docker image won't run (permission denied), and on inspection it turns out that `bin/start` is being created as an empty directory.

```
dan@cobalt:~/projects/confabulous/deva$ ls -l target/universal/stage/bin/
total 24
-rwxrw-r-- 1 dan dan 11591 Aug  5 20:44 deva
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dan dan  6211 Aug  5 20:44 deva.bat
drwxrwxr-x 2 dan dan  4096 Dec 31  1969 start
```

It also has a null timestamp for some reason. Why is it being created as a directory and not a shell script?

Here's my plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.timushev.sbt" % "sbt-updates" % "0.1.4")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.4")

addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.7.1")

addSbtPlugin("se.marcuslonnberg" % "sbt-docker" % "0.5.0")

resolvers += Classpaths.sbtPluginReleases
```

And here's my build.sbt:

```
import DockerKeys._
import sbtdocker.{Dockerfile, ImageName}
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._

organization  := "com.confabulous"

name          := "deva"

version       := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion  := "2.10.3"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8", "-language:postfixOps")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "sonatype releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/",
  "sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "typesafe repo"      at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "ch.qos.logback"      %   "logback-classic" % "1.0.9",
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %   "akka-slf4j_2.10" % "2.3.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"      % "2.3.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-remote"     % "2.3.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-agent"      % "2.3.3",
  "com.typesafe.slick"  %%  "slick"           % "2.0.1-RC1",
  "org.mozilla"         %   "rhino"           % "1.7R4",
  "org.postgresql"      %   "postgresql"      % "9.3-1101-jdbc3",
  "org.msgpack"         %%  "msgpack-scala"   % "0.6.8",
  "com.livestream"      %%  "scredis"         % "1.1.2",
  "com.confabulous"     %%  "messages"        % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "com.confabulous"     %%  "db"              % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
)

packageArchetype.java_server

sbtdocker.Plugin.dockerSettings

mappings in Universal += baseDirectory.value / "docker" / "start" -> "bin/start"

docker <<= docker.dependsOn(com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Keys.stage.in(Compile))

// Define a Dockerfile
dockerfile in docker <<= (name, stagingDirectory in Universal) map {
    case (appName, stageDir) =>
        val workingDir = s"/opt/${appName}"
        new Dockerfile {
            // Use a base image that contain Java
            from("relateiq/oracle-java7")
            maintainer("Dan Ellis <dan@halftreelabs.com>")
            expose(1600)
            add(stageDir, workingDir)
            run("chmod",  "+x",  s"/opt/${appName}/bin/${appName}")
            run("chmod",  "+x",  s"/opt/${appName}/bin/start")
            workDir(workingDir)
            entryPointShell(s"bin/start", appName, "$@")
        }
}

imageName in docker := {
    ImageName(
        namespace = Some("confabulous.com"),
        repository = name.value
        //,tag = Some("v" + version.value))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The referenced article is part 2 of a series, where the address of the container is passed into the Java program by a script. The script itself is referenced in [part 1](http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2014/03/running-an-akka-cluster-with-docker-containers/).

`mappings in Universal` takes a sequence of `(File, String)` tuples. The File is copied to the path specified by the String in the resulting image.

In this case, if there is no file present at `baseDirectory.value / "docker" / "start"`, then nothing is available to copy, and the resulting  is the behavior you describe.

You should create an appropriate start script, as discussed in part 1.

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that little one-line script. I had assumed it was a larger script sbt-native-packager generated, but it just creates the other one (`bin/deva` in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to make use of the experimental support for Docker in [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/).

If you remove the Docker-related lines from build.sbt, and add a `maintainer` setting, you can:

`sbt docker:stage` generate a Dockerfile and context in `target/docker/stage`

`sbt docker:publishLocal` generate a local image

`sbt docker:publish` generate an image and push it remotely

If you want to modify the commands passed to the start script, you can make modifications like this:

```
bashScriptExtraDefines := Seq(
  "CLUSTER_IP=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')",
  "addResidual ${CLUSTER_IP}"
)
```

`addResidual` is a function in the start script generated by sbt-native-packager, that adds an extra parameter to the command line arguments for the program.

`addJava` is a function that adds an extra parameter to the Java binary that runs your program.

---

Your `build.sbt` might look like this:

```scala
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._

organization  := "com.confabulous"

name          := "deva"

version       := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion  := "2.10.3"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8", "-language:postfixOps")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "sonatype releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/",
  "sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "typesafe repo"      at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "ch.qos.logback"      %   "logback-classic" % "1.0.9",
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %   "akka-slf4j_2.10" % "2.3.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"      % "2.3.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-remote"     % "2.3.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-agent"      % "2.3.3",
  "com.typesafe.slick"  %%  "slick"           % "2.0.1-RC1",
  "org.mozilla"         %   "rhino"           % "1.7R4",
  "org.postgresql"      %   "postgresql"      % "9.3-1101-jdbc3",
  "org.msgpack"         %%  "msgpack-scala"   % "0.6.8",
  "com.livestream"      %%  "scredis"         % "1.1.2",
  "com.confabulous"     %%  "messages"        % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "com.confabulous"     %%  "db"              % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
)

packageArchetype.java_server

maintainer := "Dan Ellis <dan@halftreelabs.com>"
```

More information should be available from the sbt-native-packager documentation. Comments are also welcome.